# Divs with variable text length alignment and centering issues

Tags: html, css, inline, centering

I'm trying to:

1. center two divs on the page
2. while keeping them inline

I can accomplish one but then the other does not work due to their differing text lengths. If I center the divs, they are out of line with one another(staggered as shown on http://willhay.io/about). I can fix this issue by floating them left, but then they are not centered. How can I both center the divs while keeping them inline with each other while they have variable text lengths?

```
<div class="bigBox">
    <div class="aboutBox">
        <img class="icon" src="../img/location.png" width="100" height="100">
        <p>I was born and raised in Atlanta, GA, with dreams of moving to California. , heart, skills, art</p>
    </div>

    <div class="aboutBox">
        <img class="icon" src="../img/music.png" width="100" height="100">
        <p>
            I love all types of music, and after watching Guardians of the Galaxy, I gained a new appreciation for 70's music. Follow my Spotify playlist, or listen to it here.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aboutBox {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    outline:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.5em;
    display:inline-block;
}

.bigBox {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: you can change the display to inline-table

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align: top;` on aboutBox divs